# How to do url rewriting in Firebase hosting Firebase.Json

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

In my website i.e in my server i have [googlee.technology/Verify/191711443.pdf](https://googlee.technology/Verify/191711443.pdf)  is there, I want to know if user enters [googlee.technology/Verify/191711443](https://googlee.technology/Verify/191711443)  without pdf extension, I want to display same results in my web page  . How to do that.
This is my Firebase.json file code:

```
{ 
  "hosting": {
    "site": "chinnapareddy",
    "public": "y",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  `"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rewrite `/Verify/191711443` to `/Verify/191711443.pdf`, you'd use this in your `firebase.json`:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/Verify/191711443",
    "destination": "/Verify/191711443.pdf"
  }]
}
```

---

Update: this is what the JSON from your last comment **should** look like:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "site": "chinnapareddy",
        "public": "y",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "/.*", "**/node_modules/"]

        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "/Verify/191711443",
            "destination": "/Verify/191711443.pdf"
        }]

    },

    "functions": {
        "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"],
        "source": "functions"
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting error when deploying code {
  "hosting": {
    "site": "chinnapareddy",
    "public": "y",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
"rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/Verify/191711443",
    "destination": "/Verify/191711443.pdf"
  }]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}

Comment: Pls provide me full working code and I added in above

Comment: Not working, it says 404 file not found............... This is code................{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "chinnapareddy",
    "public": "y",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions",
"rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/Verify/191711443",
    "destination": "/Verify/191711443.pdf"
  }]
  }
}

Comment: You've put the `rewrites` inside `functions`. As the comment says, it's supposed to go straight inside `hosting`. I updated my answer to show with the rest of your file.

Comment: Updated. But honestly, at this point I'm just parsing this doc sample for you:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example

Comment: I got , Its working , But its working only for one file i.e  /Verify/191711443 , I have another files like 191711238 , 191711285 etc under Verify folder, I need to get all these files like   /Verify/191711443

Comment: I need to get similar way for all other files under Verify folder.

Comment: I need to get multiple files in similar way how to do that, please explain

Comment: The [documentation for `rewrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) says that "`destination` is a local file that must exist". It seems that you can't do a wildcard rewrite.